# SD Card reader stopped working: cannot even mount it

Tags: drivers, mount, 14.10, sd-card

On my HP 625 Laptop running Ubuntu 14.10 with kernel 3.16.0-28, the SD card reader stopped working after some time. The last actions related to this device were installing `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` to mount SDXC cards. This was successful, but after copying some files from the card to hard drive, the device stopped working.

Now, there is nothing showing up in `cat /proc/partitions` (i.e. the output is identical before and after inserting a card (SD or SDXC, doesn't matter)).

The output of `sudo lspci` does not seem to have an SD card reader included:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS880 Host Bridge
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 9602
00:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0)
00:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 4)
00:11.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
00:12.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:12.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:13.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:13.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller (rev 42)
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller (rev 40)
00:14.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge (rev 40)
00:14.5 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller
00:16.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller
00:16.2 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor HyperTransport Configuration
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Address Map
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor DRAM Controller
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Miscellaneous Control
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 10h Processor Link Control
01:05.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880M [Mobility Radeon HD 4225/4250]
01:05.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RS880 HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 4200 Series]
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 02)
03:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

The output of `lsusb` doesn't look like it contains anything card reader related either:

```
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b1ac Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

`dmesg | grep -i "card"` only outputs sound card related stuff.

Uninstalling `exfat-fuse exfat-utils` does not change anything, and neither does reinstalling the packages.

The device is enabled in BIOS.

It seems like the drivers for this device disappeared, doesn't it? How do I re-enable this?

Comment: If you have Windows, go into that and see if the SD reader is detected. I think it may have broken.

Comment: Card readers are almost always attached via USB, so try `lsusb` instead of `lspci`.

Comment: @Cmdr I added the output, but I guess it's not helpful.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I don't have an alternative OS on this machine.

Comment: I didn't think you did, but I suggested it anyway. Do you have a hard drive with Windows on it?

Comment: @Zacharee1 Nothing that I can insert into this laptop, no. But thanks for your ideas.

Comment: Have you tried using a LiveCD?

Comment: @Zacharee1 I don't have one lying around and if possible, I'd like to fix this issue without external operating systems ;-)

Comment: Do you have a USB stick? This would be a good way to see if it's actually broken or if it's just your OS. This would be the first step I'd take. If it's broken, there's nothing we can do.

Comment: There's no point trying to fix something if it's a hardware problem.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I don't have any such tool available to me right now. I consider the likelyhood if a hardware problem to be very low, keeping in mind that there was no unusual action immediately prior to the failure.

Comment: That's the thing about hardware, though. It fails when least expected. I'm going to read through your question again, just to see if maybe it is software.

Comment: So it does look like it's not being found at all. The only devices being found are controllers and your WiFi card.

Comment: Are you able to disable/enable it in BIOS?

Answer (score 3):

Try this, your machine is now on, then:

1. Pop slowly out and then slowly in sd-card.
2. Type this into terminal

   ```
   sudo apt-get install --reinstall udev*
   ```

Then when finish then repeat with `1.` and then after this `reboot` your machine or shut completely down and boot up again without being online.

(the latter two lines are meant as in case sd-card would still not be recognized somehow you should not be `sudo` in the moment you are online).